# Is it acceptable to say 我的名字是……?

Tags: word-choice

I only remember seeing 我的名字叫……

Would 我的名字**是**…… also be an acceptable choice?

Comment: Yes, it's acceptable.

Comment: I won't respond if been asked "你的名字**叫**什么?", but both "我的名字叫/是..." are perfectly fine.

Comment: you can say 我叫 xxx

Answer (score 3):

that's right.我的名字是 = my name is

Answer (score 1):

If I don't know your name I may ask: 你的名字是什么？

So of course you could reply: 我的名字是恩瑞克。 or 我的名字叫恩瑞克。 或者 我叫恩瑞克。

Answer (score 0):

Adding to dan's comment...
For short phrases like this you can often see if they work by searching with quotes for the full phrase. Searching for "名字是" quickly gets you to a bunch of book and movie titles, so it looks like you're good to go.
You can also check stuff like this with google ngrams
https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=%E5%90%8D%E5%AD%97%E6%98%AF%2C%E5%90%8D%E5%AD%97%E5%8F%AB&year_start=1800&year_end=2000&corpus=23&smoothing=3&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2C%E5%90%8D%E5%AD%97%20%E6%98%AF%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2C%E5%90%8D%E5%AD%97%20%E5%8F%AB%3B%2Cc0
That doesn't give you context, so "名字是" is getting a boost from a bunch of contexts you're not interested in like 这个名字是很吉祥的 or something. The ngrams trick doesn't tell you how to use 名字是 or whatever you're looking up correctly, which is a pretty major downside. But, if a combination is *not* possible, you'll get a clear unambiguous negative, so it's still useful.

Answer (score 0):

YES, it is correct.

我的名字是……    =   My name is ...
我的名字叫……    =   My name is ...
我是……         =   I am

Answer (score 0):

Simply use 我叫... in daily conversation would be fine. 我的名字是...or 我的名字叫... is absolutely correct, no problem at all.

Answer (score 0):

It is acceptable to say 我的名字是......

But, we Chinese do not use this a lot, we usually say

我叫...... I'm called......
我是...... I’m ......

Hope this can help.

Answer (score -5):

日本語（日语／日語）：
私の名前はダヴィドです。
简体中文（簡體中文，日：簡体字中国語）：
我的名字是大卫。／我的名字叫大卫。
繁體中文（繁体中文，日：繁体字中国語）：
我的名字是大衛。／我的名字叫大衛。
英语／英語：《My name is David》

日本語（日语／日語）：
私はダヴィドです。
简体中文（簡體中文，日：簡体字中国語）：
我是大卫。／我叫大卫。
繁體中文（繁体中文，日：繁体字中国語）：
我是大衛。／我叫大衛。
英语／英語：《I'm David》